# Can JSRT be used on Windows 7 with IE9+, or do I need to redistribute ChakraCore?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, react-native, microsoft-edge, chakra

Several projects, like react-native-windows, make use of the JSRT wrapper API that interfaces to Chakra installations on Windows 10.

Since Chakra started shipping in Internet Explorer 9, can I use that same JSRT wrapper on Windows 7 (SP1) if IE9 or newer is installed? IE11? Or do I need to build and redistribute ChakraCore with my application on any Windows version before 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt you will need to redistribute chakracore with your application. the version of chakra that shipped in windows 7 through 8.1 was packaged in jscript9.dll. starting with windows 10 Microsoft forked the old JSRT API and stripped out all the legacy code from it and created chakra.dll. chakracore is a subset of what ships in chakra.dll (minus all of the hosting, COM, & DOM specific parts).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For anyone looking into the same thing, we built ChakraCore for Windows 7/8.1/10 and are using it in our react-native-windows application. It works great, and also gave us the advantage of doing a profile-optimized build of ChakraCore for our exact use case which reduced the binary size by 1MB and improved several benchmarks by 20-30%.